# How to create a list of properties for an item? LinkedList, ArrayList, Files?

Tags: java

I am not sure if this is a correct question for stackoverflow but I will try it anyhow.

I am trying to simulate a production system, where several parts enter a system to be operated in different machines. I'm trying to keep things simples, but to move along, I need to create some sort of list that allows me to index properties and values to an "object" like so:

```
 Machine [num][type][avg_time][posx][posy][state]
 Part [num][type][order][state]
```

So that I could create some sort of list which would allow me to retrieve a property at any given time, for instance:

```
 Machine [1][a][19][100][100][busy]

 and Machine[posx] would retrieve the saved value for it
```

I'm still reading further on ArrayLists, LinkedLists and such but can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. What's the best way to do this, so I can further read on the subject?

Comment: You may create `Machine` and `Part` classes with the attributes you already described.

Answer (score 1):

`Enums` and `HashMap` could let you do this:

```
public enum Properties {
 POSX, POSY, ...
}

Map<Properties, Value> machine = new HashMap<Properties, Value>();
```

To set the value ....

```
machine.put(Properties.POSX, 151); //if Value is of Integer class, perhaps
```

And to retrieve the value...

```
machine.get(Properties.POSX)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look further in detail on those!

However, I read somewhere that Enum constants are implicitly static and final and can not be changed once created! Being that I will have a UI in which the parameters for both Machine and Part (in this case) will be different on every run, won't that be a problem, or am I interpreting this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned problem points towards the collection know as **Maps**.

Choose one from the below, which you find more suitable for your problem.

**1.** If you want the Properties to be in **sorted order use TreeMap.**

**2.** If you want the **quickest** among the Map, then go for **HashMap.**

**3.** If you want the Map to be **thread safe**, then go for **HashTable.**

**4.** For **thread safety you can also use ConcurrentHashMap**, from java.util.concurrent
       package.

**eg:**

```
HashMap<Properties, Value> myMachine = new HashMap<Properties, Value>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look further in detail on those to find out what will suit me best!

Comment: I found both Treemap and Hash useful! For now, I will use Treemaps, I believe it suits my needs!

One small question, is it possible to use a class to do assign all the values to the map, and then use them on another class?

Comment: Ya possible.... Remember this principle of software engineering.. `"A class should do only One thing, so it will have only One reason to change."`